# Barebones dynamic report tool for SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

[Ms SQL]

I've got some data dense sql queries that I view the results of through the SSMS u/i in the datagrid.

The queries are saved as stored procedures that select multiple result sets.

I would like to be able to control the grid formatting a bit more (eg override column widths, decimal formats, right justify numbers, etc).

Is there an alternative to SSMS that would give me more control of the data presentation?  It needs to be dynamic and not require a bunch of coding to display a new query (lots of sql work is ad hoc data exploration).

Comment: why is my question downvoted???

Answer (score 1):

You can set up a data source in an Excel workbook, as long as the dataset isn't too huge.

https://blogs.office.com/2010/06/07/running-a-sql-stored-procedure-from-excel-no-vba/

You could also use SSRS, but Excel would be the fastest way to get going. SSRS is a little more work and probably not what you're looking for.

Edit - you said it returns multiple datasets. I'm not sure that Excel can handle that properly.

Comment: yeah, would be a good solution if not for the mutliple data sets.

Comment: Honestly I can't think of any solution which is both simple to setup and modify, and will also let you work with multiple result sets returned from stored procs. Excel is going to be your best bet, if only you can modify your sprocs to return one dataset per query. There are ways to pump multiple datasets from one query into excel, but they are definitely not trivial to setup and modify. Even most enterprise reporting tools only support one dataset per sql command.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose it depends entirely on what you're already comfortable with. Winforms + DataGridView controls inside TabControl objects are *really* easy to set up. Mostly you just bind the data to the DataGridView controls and they do the right thing based in data types. DataGridView has a virtual mode if your data is real freaking big (gives you control over paging, etc)..but this requires actual code. Old, easy and pretty robust if you're on windows UI...which is assumed given you're into the SSMS UI. Minimal C# or VB.Net required.